# remove mapkit overlays on iphone

Tags: iphone, mapkit, overlay

How do I remove all overlays on mapkit?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try

```
[mapView removeOverlays: mapView.overlays];
```

Comment: Works for me, make sure you have the correct method, mapView.removeOverlays(mapView.overlays) as there is also mapView.removeOverlay

Answer (score 4):

```
[mapView removeOverlays:[mapView overlays]];
```